# can this regular expression find/replace be optimised?

Tags: php, regex

simple one really, i've written a regular expression to find and replace tags with php constants from within a html snippet. my solution, which works, just doesn't feel right. how can this be improved?

```
preg_match_all('/\{CONSTANT_(.*)\}/', $final, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[1]); $i++) {
               $final = str_replace($result[0][$i], constant($result[1][$i]),$final);
            }
```

Comment: Aren't you lacking a `?` in your `(.*)` ? (i.e. should be `(.*?)\}` or use the U / PCRE_UNGREEDY modifier, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php#regexp.reference.internal-options)
I think you are performing a greedy search, so if you have `"{CONSTANT_c1}{CONSTANT_c2}"`, the `(.*)` capturing group would match `"c1}{CONSTANT_c2"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in one hit with [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

```
function getConstant($matches) 
{
    return constant($matches[1]);
}
$final=preg_replace_callback(
           '/\{CONSTANT_(.*?)\}/',
           "getConstant",
           $final);
```

Note I've made the `.*` non greedy with `.*?`, this will have the effect of ensuring it doesn't go eating a } if a longer match is possible. You could get the same effect with `([^}]*)`, or better yet, `([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)`

Comment: yeah, that looks like just what i need actually. seems more elegant and efficient

Comment: "[^}]}+" is even better than "(.*?)\}"

Answer (score 0):

I'm always against reinventing the wheel: if you need some sort of template engine (which php already is) take a look at [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net).

Comment: this is true but implementing Smarty just seems overkill for this usage and presumably comes with its own inherent overhead anyway

Answer (score 0):

What about

`mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit= -1 [, int &$count ]] )`

?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with using "`.*`" in a regular expression, as it will greedily match everything it finds. For example, in the following line:

```
{CONSTANT_ONE} blah {CONSTANT_TWO}
```

The above regular expression will capture the string "`ONE} blah {CONSTANT_TWO`"

You could use a character class instead of . to match anything except a "`}`" character:

```
/\{CONSTANT_([^}]*)\}/
```

Comment: Surely you could just use the none greedy operator in a preg, e.g. .*?